# how to set expiration time for SqlNormalizedCacheFactory in apollo-kotlin client

Tags: kotlin, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-kotlin

With MemoryCacheFactory you can pass in an expiration time as an argument:

```
MemoryCacheFactory(maxSizeBytes = 10 * 1024 * 1024, expireAfterMillis = 1000)
```

how do i do something similar with `SqlNormalizedCacheFactory`?